# R alternative to scikit-learn

Tags: r, machine-learning, scikit-learn, software, mlr

As a statics researcher, I've been using R since university and I know it quite well, I also know that it's immediate, but it quickly gets chaotic, and this also happens because of the variety and inconsistency of the packages and object types.

I've came to know scikit-learn some years ago, and since then I've always used that package for machine learning, it's so neat and really helps you doing things in the right way! I learned to use pandas, which is very nice but too unpredictable and also quite bugged, and some matplotlib, which is indisputably versatile, but frankly, so hard and time consuming!

For these and further reasons still, I would like to move back to R, but I know I would miss scikit-learn. I never really liked caret, but I have to admit I never really gave it a chance, mlr3 seems more promising, but maybe mlr is a good option too.

One good thing I want to have is fully customizable pipelines, that can take in custom functions or classes. This is fairly easy in python.

Do you have any recommendations about where to look, what to learn? pros and cons over python tools?

Comment: Caret seems to be your best bet.

Comment: thanks for your comment. I'm looking for answers that elaborate and motivate a suggestion like that, so I can relate to the arguments and make a decision.

Comment: Everyone commenting here probably has its workhorse and is biased. Most have not tried all of the available ones. All the frameworks excel in different points. I would just not use the ones that are deprecated (caret + mlr). Make your own choice. At least R has different frameworks for ML and proper implementations of algorithms ;)

Comment: @pat-s caret is deprecated?

Comment: by the way, I don't know any other framework for ML in R

Comment: The main dev and creator (Max Kuhn) is working full-time on tidymodels, it's successor. Maybe somebody from the community picks it up. But better check yourself 

Comment: I think you can refer to this article: https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/MachineLearning.html

Comment: Caret has been superseded by tidymodels, which offers more models, it's easier to expand... but it uses dplyr syntax.
I prefer mlr3.